# Is There a Profiler for Windows Scripting Host Code?

Tags: profiling, wsh, windows-scripting

Are there any profilers that can profile code that runs under WSH (VBScript, JavaScript, WSF)? Other than hand instrumenting with trace statements, what's a good way to profile code running under WSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/script-profiling/) can do that.  They have a free trial available.

> You can use AQtime to profile scripts
>   executed by the Microsoft Scripting
>   Engine. The engine supports the
>   VBScript and JScript languages and is
>   used by applications like Internet
>   Explorer, Windows Script Host or
>   TestComplete. Thus, you can use AQtime
>   to profile VBScript and JScript
>   routines that are executed in these
>   applications. For instance, you can
>   profile scripts that reside on your
>   web pages or you can profile scripts
>   of your TestComplete project.